# Check if PostgreSQL dump is valid

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11

Suppose a dump is provided from pgdumpall

```
pg_dumpall > outfile.bkp
```

How to verify if the outfile is a vaild database file for restoration. Just as a precautionary step before restoring it like

```
psql -f outfile.bkp postgres
```

For example: In MySQL we can head first few lines of the backup files produced from **mysqldump** for having SQL like syntax.

Comment: If `pg_dumpall` did not result in an error you can be certain the file is valid.

Comment: What if it is provided by application team and System DBA has to restore it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command you show generates a text backup file.  You can use "head" or "less" on it to verify that it looks like a PostgreSQL text backup file, same as mysql.  I'd also run "tail", just to make sure it didn't get truncated.  It should end with a sign-off like:

```
--
-- PostgreSQL database dump complete
--

--
-- PostgreSQL database cluster dump complete
--
```

Of course to be really sure, you would just set up a dummy database server, and restore it.